# How use python to plot multiple lines in a single figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use python to plot multiple lines like following. Each line has a value between 0 and 1. Can anyone help me?

[image]

I use `plt.subplots()` to accomplish this, but i cannot remove the x_axis between lines.

Comment: Please add the code for what you've tried and an input sample.

Comment: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZZvg.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if subplots were used to achieve the graph on your screenshot.  It can be plotted just by adding 1*i to each plotted y-vector so that they do not intersect. `10` on the top left of your screenshot suggests that.

I generated random vectors with values between 0 and 1 and plotted them like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
n = 10
ys = [(np.sin(x * (i + 1)) + 1) / 2 for i in range(n)]

for i, y in enumerate(ys):
    plt.plot(x, y + i, label=str(i))
```

Output:
[image]